# Export users from AD with a specific group membership

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that takes all the users in the AD and getting four specifics.

1. saMAccountName
2. Displayname
3. Comment
4. Specific group name (Group A)

Below is the code that I have now. It works, but it gives me all the groups, I only need one specific group (Group A) to be listed.
If the user is not a member of this group, the user must be listed in the export but without the listing of the group

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Domain Users"} | 
Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
Get-ADUser -Properties comment,displayname,MemberOf | 
select saMAccountName,displayname,comment,@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={$_.MemberOf -Join ";"}} | 
Sort-Object SamAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Install\Export-AD.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope you have some tips and pointers for me on how to filter on the group name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a comparison operation (`-like`) to your expression for `MemberOf`. You can see an example of this below. However, I would recommend against that single augmentation because of the **inefficient** nature of the `Where-Object` and the **unnecessary queries** that are happening here.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Domain Users"} | Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | Get-ADUser -Properties comment,displayname,MemberOf | select saMAccountName,displayname,comment,@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={($_.MemberOf -like "Group A") -join ";"}} | Sort-Object SamAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Install\Export-AD.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I don't know how efficiently this runs in your AD. I tested this with a 722 member group, and it took **22.221 seconds** to run.

I would try something like this instead as it will be **significantly faster**:

```
$GroupFilterDN = (Get-ADGroup "DOMAIN users").DistinguishedName
$GroupCheck = (Get-ADGroup "Group A").DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -filter {(memberof -eq $GroupFilterDN -or PrimaryGroup -eq $GroupFilterDN) -and (ObjectClass -eq "user")} -Properties comment,displayname,MemberOf | 
select saMAccountName,displayname,comment,@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={$_.MemberOf.where({$_ -in $GroupCheck}) -join ";"}} | 
Sort-Object SamAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Install\Export-AD.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You need to replace the `Group A` string with your group name in the `$GroupCheck` variable.
`$GroupFilter` contains the group you want to filter on. In your example, you wanted to filter on Domain Users. The variable holds the DN for that group.
`$GroupCheck` contains the group for which you want to find members. The variable holds the DN for that group. In your example, you called this Group A.
The `PrimaryGroup` check had to be added since in your example you are using Domain Users. Domain Users does not show up in the `MemberOf` property.
The `where({$_ -in $GroupCheck})` method is for when `$GroupCheck` has multiple groups. `$GroupCheck` currently would only have one group, but it could be tweaked to have multiple.

The code removes the requirement of using the `Get-ADGroupMember` command, which contains the `Where-Object`. Then it adds a comparison operation (`-eq`) for the `MemberOf` expression.

I tested the second block of code and it completed in **3.847 seconds** with the same 722 member group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've removed the Where-Object.

But the query returns 0 groups, with your -Like

Comment: @MrWeasel, Please try my second example instead.

Comment: Thanks for that help, looks like it’s working.
Just one more thing.
Can we make the following code to use a wildcard?
`$GroupCheck = (Get-ADGroup "Group A").DistinguishedName`

I tried to do: 
`$GroupCheck = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like Groep*"}).DistinguishedName`

The command itself works but the csv isn’t with this change.

Comment: @MrWeasel, `$GroupCheck` should only store the DN. You can set up the query however you like as long as the DN for the object is assigned to the variable. The command won't give you an error if it finds no group using the `-filter` parameter. When you change `$GroupCheck`, you should type `$GroupCheck` at the console to see if it actually has a value. When using wildcards on the `-like` operator, you need to make sure that if one side of the string does not have a wildcard, that it is in fact the beginning or the end of the string. Please make sure to recopy my code as I made an update.

Comment: @MrWeasel, I do not know if I fully answered your question about changing `$GroupCheck`. `(Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*Group*"}).DistinguishedName` should be sufficient for what you want to do.

Comment: I altered the code, to use  `-Filter`

`$GroupCheck = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Group*"}).DistinguishedName`

The `$GroupCheck` is filled with a number of groups, which is good.
But the collom MemberOf in the csv remains empty

Comment: @MrWeasel, so you are saying that you want to check memberOf for multiple groups instead of just one group? `$GroupCheck` is intended to have one group.

Comment: Sorry about that, guess I should have stated that earlier on.
If just thought that I could change the code to use a `–Filter` with multiple entries

Just to clarify 
I’m looking for a list with users and when the user is a member of a group beginning with `group*`
Then that group need to be added to the collom

Comment: @MrWeasel, I have updated the code to use multiple groups now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help.
I got exactly what I need.